# How to make an ASP.NET control QTP safe?

Tags: asp.net, qtp

Is there any way to make ASP.NET control QTP safe ? By QTP safe I mean QTP should not be able detect them on UI. I have tried to change access modifiers to private but that does not work.

Is it not possible at all ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

No. QTP can detect basic HTML elements，which ASP.NET controls are built upon.

If you want to prevent your website from being automated by QTP, you may consider some [CAPTCHA](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/CAPTCHA) techniques.